# How to improve the scroll performance of webapp in webview of retina device

Tags: javascript, web-applications, iphone-web-app

I have a iPad3(ios5):
I load my webapp html locally,I disable all the css3 effect like `box-shadow`and everything I can optimize like what I used to optimized a website, etc.
And All my effort focus on css/html(I don't even execute any javascript),yet I still couldn't get to a tolerable fps

did I miss something?Is it just a performance issue like a bug or something else in ios5?
What's the best practice to improve the scroll performance in webapp?

Comment: Do you have an URL for the site where it could be tested? It's hard to make guesses.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with most likely the same problem ([see my SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9972690/474535))

I do use iScroll and recently I had another performance issue in iOS6.1.3 but with the iScroll itself. I was able to solve it by explicitly add `css` to get hardware acceleration on the iScroll.

I used a specific page `id` to assign the `css` but you can decide yourself where you need to add it if it would help for your case as well.

**CSS:**

```
#myid * {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

my iscroll uses the classes `s-scrollwrapper` and `s-scrollpane` which might be better choices to add the css to enforce hardware acceleration. Then the `css` would be

```
.s-scrollwrapper * {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

or

```
.s-scrollpane * {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Hope this helps you improving the speed on iOS5 as well.

[Webapp on iPad 3 retina display slow screen painting](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9972690/474535)